# Deferred() only make 2 functions asynchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, jquery-deferred

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x89ja8r8/

I have been looking around to find a quick way to chain function async. Stackoverflow offers a lot of "same" solutions, but when I tried it, something is always wrong.

In the example below, I have 3 functions. I try to chain them asynchronously using $.Deffer().

**Expectation**: The div will animate to change its dimension for the duration of 5500ms, **then** the div will fade to 0.25 opacity in the duration of 2000ms, **then** the div innerHTML will be changed to DONE!

**Result**: The div changes its innerHTML (from fn3()) **simultaneously** with its changing its dimension (from fn1()) for the duration of 5500ms, **then** it fades to 0.25 opacity in the duration of 2000ms (from fn2()).

```
function fn1() {

  $("#result").animate({
    width: 800,
    height: 800
  }, 5500);

}

function fn2() {

  $("#result").animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  }, 2000);

}

function fn3() {

  $("#result").html("DONE!");

}

var dfr = $.Deferred();

dfr.done(fn1, fn2, fn3).resolve();
```

What is wrong here? If it didn't work at all, there should not be the async between fn1() and fn2(). The result shows clearly that fn2() does wait for fn1() to finish, but fn3() just kicks in without even waiting.

Comment: The 2 functions which are behaving in sequence are doing so because `.animate()` has the special behavior of waiting until all other animations are finished on that element before starting.

Answer (score 0):

dfr.done(fn1, fn2, fn3) will execute all the functions at the same time, not in a sequential order. Since $.animate() is an asynchronous operation, according to jQuery's documentation, it can either take in a callback that will be called once the animation finishes, or you can have it return a promise. You will then have to chain the promises using $.Deferred.then(), like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function fn1() {
    return $("#result").animate({
      width: 800,
      height: 800
    }, 5500).promise();
  }

  function fn2() {
    return $("#result").animate({
      opacity: 0.25
    }, 2000).promise();
  }

  function fn3() {
    return $("#result").html("DONE!").delay(2000).promise();
  }

  function fn4() {
    var fn4Dfr = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#result").html("Okay!");
      fn4Dfr.resolve();
    }, 2000);
    return fn4Dfr;
  }

  var dfr = $.Deferred();
  dfr.then(fn1).then(fn2).then(fn3).then(fn4);
  dfr.resolve();
});
```

fn3 uses delay, which behaves like a setTimeout, and fn4 uses setTimeout, so we create a promise which we can resolve as needed (and return the promise immediately).

Comment: Hi, Bao. Thank you for your response. Now that I know $.animate() is async themselves, what happen if I have another fn4() that is not a async function? How do I chain them then, because I tried here https://jsfiddle.net/x89ja8r8/ and it didn't work as expected.

Comment: I included an example of using $.delay() which has a promise in fn3. For fn4, if you decide to execute something that has no promise, then you can create one and resolve when it's done. https://jsfiddle.net/52fvv0xw/

Comment: So, given a pure javascript function fn(){ /*code goes here */ }, is there any way to make that function a promise woth jQuery?

Comment: I just updated my answer https://jsfiddle.net/52fvv0xw/ look at fn4 as an example.

Comment: Perfect, bao. Can you please update that fiddle as your answer. This is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular use case, you can use a simple callback instead of `$.Deferred`:

```js
$("#result")
.animate({ width: 800, height: 800 }, 5500)
.animate({ opacity: 0.25 }, 2000, function () {
  $(this).text('Done!')
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">Result</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your suggestion. However, I need to Deferred() because I need to chain functions() (pure javascript) that might not be async functions themselves. If you have 4 functions, how would you execute them in order asynchronously?

Comment: Hi. I've tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/x89ja8r8/1/ but it didn't work out as expected.

Comment: Hi, gyre. That fiddle doesn't have that 2 seconds wait on fn3(). The goal is to execute fn1() for 5.5 seconds, then execute fn2() for 2 seconds, then wait 2 seconds to execute fn3(), **then** wait 2 seconds to execute fn4().

Comment: The idea is correct, gyre. However, the fn4 doesn't wait for fn3 to complete! Both of them are fired at the same time and there is no wait between fn3 and fn4.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to change the delay for `fn4` to 4s. Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/x89ja8r8/4/

Comment: Thank you, gyre, for the suggestion. That is a workaround, but it doesn't solve the original problem. The goal is to execute those functions one after another. Or did I miss something regarding setTimeout() or if it is even achievable via javascript?

Comment: Make a `wait` utility that returns a deferred that resolves after x ms; see https://jsfiddle.net/x89ja8r8/5/

Answer (score 0):

> I have been looking around to find a quick way to chain function async.

The [`done` method](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) does not chain anything. It installs handlers to run, and if you pass multiple arguments it will call the functions at the same time. `done` should never be used.

What you are looking for is the [`then` method](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) of promises, which returns a *new promise* that will resolve with the result of the callback (waiting when it returns another promise). Actually you don't need deferreds at all!

```
function fn1() {
  return $("#result").animate({
    width: 800,
    height: 800
  }, 5500).promise();
}
function fn2() {
  return $("#result").animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  }, 2000).promise();
}
function fn3() {
  $("#result").html("DONE!");
}

fn1().then(fn2).then(fn2);
```